# Get drop down value

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How to determine what is selected in the drop down? In Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get selected value of dropdownlist using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: It's usually quite helpful if you include some code in your questions

Answer (score 35):

If your dropdown is something like this:

```
<select id="thedropdown">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Then you would use something like:

```
var a = document.getElementById("thedropdown");
alert(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);
```

But a library like jQuery simplifies things:

```
alert($('#thedropdown').val());
```

Comment: I'm digging deep in my memory here, but I think `a.value` didn't work in some browsers (probably IE 6, haha). Anyway, using a library is best.

Comment: It works on all browsers that I know of, including IE6. (just tested)

Comment: It happened in very old browsers like Netscape Navigator 4. [Look](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/90872-how-get-selected-value-select-using-dom)

Answer (score 7):

Use the `value` property of the `<select>` element. For example:

```
var value = document.getElementById('your_select_id').value;
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<select onchange = "selectChanged(this.value)">
  <item value = "1">one</item>
  <item value = "2">two</item>
</select>
```

and then the javascript...

```
function selectChanged(newvalue) {
  alert("you chose: " + newvalue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dd = document.getElementById("dropdownID");
var selectedItem = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$dd = document.getElementById("yourselectelementid");
$so = $dd.options[$dd.selectedIndex];
```