# Get selected value/text from Select on change

Tags: javascript

```
<select onchange="test()" id="select_id">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Communication</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the value of the selected option in javascript: does anyone know how to get the selected value or text, please tell how to write a function for it. I have assigned onchange() function to select so what do i do after that?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029281/get-drop-down-value

Comment: If you only want the `value` of the `option` that was selected then... `<select onchange="window.alert(this.value);">`... _`option`s_...`</select>`... should get ya just that and nothing more.

Answer (score 184):

Use either JavaScript or jQuery for this.

**Using JavaScript**

```
<script>
function val() {
    d = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
    alert(d);
}
</script>

<select onchange="val()" id="select_id">
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$('#select_id').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: .value() works on modern browsers but not on really old ones. See http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/90872-how-get-selected-value-select-using-dom

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro That is the selected value. If you wanted the text (e.g. -Select- or Communication) you would use text: `select.text` or in jQuery `select.text()`.

Comment: Using jQuery `$('#select_id option:selected').text()` .This will return the text of the option selected, _Select_ or _Communication_

Comment: vanilla javascript approach:  ```document.getElementById("select_id").onchange = (evt) => {
        console.log(evt.srcElement.value);
    }```

Comment: I would not rely on `getElementById` as you can potentially use the same method for different selects. I'd look at the answer proposed by YakovL if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 109):

If you're googling this, and don't want the event listener to be an attribute, use:

```js
document.getElementById('my-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('You selected: ', this.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In certain cases where function scope changes, `this` doesn't work. Better do `const mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select'); mySelect.addEventListener('change', function() { console.log('You selected: ', mySelect.value);});`

Comment: Doesn't work for arrow functions

Answer (score 62):

Wow, no really reusable solutions among answers yet.. I mean, a standard event handler should get only an `event` argument and doesn't have to use ids at all.. I'd use:

```
function handleSelectChange(event) {

    // if you want to support some really old IEs, add
    // event = event || window.event;

    var selectElement = event.target;

    var value = selectElement.value;
    // to support really old browsers, you may use
    // selectElement.value || selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
    // like el Dude has suggested

    // do whatever you want with the value
}
```

You may use this handler with each – inline js:

```
<select onchange="handleSelectChange(event)">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#select_id').on('change',handleSelectChange);
```

or vanilla JS handler setting:

```
var selector = document.getElementById("select_id");
selector.onchange = handleSelectChange;
// or
selector.addEventListener('change', handleSelectChange);
```

And don't have to rewrite this for each `select` element you have.

Example snippet:

```js
function handleSelectChange(event) {

    var selectElement = event.target;
    var value = selectElement.value;
    alert(value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="handleSelectChange(event)">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great solution, should be accepted. Using pure event element, without referencing DOM document is the most flexible way which works in many environments like React, Vue or just plain HTML forms.

Comment: Great solution thanks. But I think its not an event that is send, but simply the document object model of the select tag

Comment: Hey @Adam, `event.target` is the DOM represenation of the `select` element, but it's not clear what do you mean by "send" anyway (and for which approach), so I can't provide you a definitive link. You can try to `console.log` the argument and see the type yourself in your case

Answer (score 39):

```js
function test(a) {
    var x = (a.value || a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);  //crossbrowser solution =)
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="test(this)" id="select_id">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Communication</option>
    <option value="2">Communication</option>
    <option value="3">Communication</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is `a.value` for? Is there any browsers that actually support such? can't we just use `a.options[a.selectedIndex].value`?

Comment: @Anonymous< to get the subj =)

Answer (score 32):

No need for an onchange function. You can grab the value in one line:

```
document.getElementById("select_id").options[document.getElementById("select_id").selectedIndex].value;
```

Or, split it up for better readability:

```
var select_id = document.getElementById("select_id");

select_id.options[select_id.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 18):

```
let dropdown = document.querySelector('select');
if (dropdown) dropdown.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

Comment: This approach is helpful if you are working with arrow functions.

Comment: any arrow function can be replaced with function() {}, it's the same thing

Comment: it isn't the same. `this` in an arrow function gets its context from its lexical environment but the normal function has its own this. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. You can store this in a variable outside the anonymous function to ensure you can get the correct scope you need

Answer (score 9):

HTML:

```
<select onchange="cityChanged(this.value)">
      <option value="CHICAGO">Chicago</option>
      <option value="NEWYORK">New York</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function cityChanged(city) {
    alert(city);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I wonder that everyone has posted about `value` and `text` option to get from `<option>` and no one suggested `label`.

So I am suggesting `label` too, as supported by all browsers

To get `value` (same as others suggested)

```
function test(a) {
var x = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
alert(x);
}
```

To get `option` `text` (i.e. Communication or -Select-)

```
function test(a) {
var x = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;
alert(x);
}
```

**OR**  (New suggestion)

```
function test(a) {
var x = a.options[a.selectedIndex].label;
alert(x);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="test(this)" id="select_id">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Communication</option>
    <option value="2" label=‘newText’>Communication</option>
</select>
```

> Note: In above HTML for `option` value 2, `label` will return **newText** instead of **Communication**

Also

> Note: It is not possible to set the label property in Firefox (only return).

Answer (score 8):

Why overcomplicate it:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select#id.orClass');
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(select.value);

  // or if it changes dynamically
  console.log(e.target.value);      
});
```

```js
 let select = document.getElementById('select_id');
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(select.value);
    // just for test
    alert(select.value);
  });
```

```html
<select id="select_id">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Communication</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
document.getElementById("select_id").selectedIndex
```

Or to get the value:

```
document.getElementById("select_id").value
```

Comment: this way of getting the value won't work in old browsers, use Danny's solution instead

Answer (score 7):

```
<script>
function test(a) {
    var x = a.selectedIndex;
    alert(x);
}
</script>
<select onchange="test(this)" id="select_id">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Communication</option>
    <option value="2">Communication</option>
    <option value="3">Communication</option>
</select>
```

in the alert you'll see the INT value of the selected index, treat the selection as an array and you'll get the value

Answer (score 6):

```js
        $('#select_id').change(function(){
        // selected value 
        alert($(this).val());
        // selected text 
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="test()" id="select_id">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="1">Communication</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I am not sure why people didn't suggest using the event object to retrieve the info instead of searching through the DOM again.

Simply go through the event object in your function onChange, see example bellow

`function test() {
    console.log(event.srcElement.value);
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/Corsico/3yvh9wc6/5/

Might be useful to people looking this up today if this wasn't default behavior 7 years ago

Comment: well.. some did :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47495878/3995261

Answer (score 4):

In html

```
(change)="onChangeCategory($event)"
```

In javascript/typescript

```
onChangeCategory(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].value);
    console.log(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function test(){
  var sel1 = document.getElementById("select_id");
  var strUser1 = sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(strUser1);
  alert(strUser1);
  // Inorder to get the Test as value i.e "Communication"
  var sel2 = document.getElementById("select_id");
  var strUser2 = sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(strUser2);
  alert(strUser2);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="test()" id="select_id">
  <option value="0">-Select-</option>
  <option value="1">Communication</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value from the select element by passing "this.value" as a parameter to your function named `test(this.value)` and after that
You should create the function with a parameter inside the script element and finally you can write `console.log(number)` inside this function to get Your selected value.

```js
function test(number) {
  console.log(number)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
  <select onchange="test(this.value)" id="select_id">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Communication</option>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the `onChange` is invoked you can add either JS or JQuery Code Snippet to get your thought working.

```
//Javascript

document.getElementById("select_id").selectedIndex // prints text value of the option
document.getElementById("select_id").value // prints the value of the option 

//JQUERY 

var selected = $('#select_id option:selected').val(); 
// prints the **value** of the option clicked in the dropdown
    
var selected = $('#select_id option:selected').html(); 
// prints the **text** of the option clicked in the dropdown
```

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but are you sure it's a good idea to still suggest using id while a handler can use `event.target` instead (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47495878/3995261)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(){
  var sel1 = document.getElementById("select_id");
  var strUser1 = sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(strUser1);
  alert(strUser1);
  // Inorder to get the Test as value i.e "Communication"
  var sel2 = document.getElementById("select_id");
  var strUser2 = sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(strUser2);
  alert(strUser2);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="test()" id="select_id">
  <option value="0">-Select-</option>
  <option value="1">Communication</option>
</select>
```

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score -1):

You set the onchange handler to some function or string. In it, you write code to get value

```js
document.getElementById('cphForm_ddlFacility').value;
```

or, for older browsers

```js
document.getElementById('cphForm_ddlFacility')[document.getElementById('cphForm_ddlFacility').selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but are you sure it's a good idea to still suggest using id while a handler can use `event.target` instead (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47495878/3995261)?