# Set variable value from input before submit

Tags: javascript, html-select

First, I have this input in a form.

```
<select id="entry_14">
     <option value="Woman">Woman</option>
     <option value="Man">Man</option>
</select>
```

Then I declared this variable.

```
var mygender = document.getElementById('entry_14').value;
```

but then, when I document.write, it already shows "Man" before the user even makes a selection, and after selecting woman, it still shows man.

How can I set the value of this variable to change, each time the user selects one of the options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value/text from Select on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/get-selected-value-text-from-select-on-change)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It executes immediately because your code is not in a function. You need to call this function when the select changes. Add an `onchange` handler to your `select.` In this example I pass `this.value` which is your select lists value to the function. Finally you can do whatever you want with that value.

```
<select id="entry_14" onchange="myfunction(this.value);">
    <option value="Woman">Woman</option> 
    <option  value="Man">Man</option>
</select>

<script>
    function myfunction(val) {
        document.write(val);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In IE, if the user is navigating the options using the cursor keys, the onchange listener will be called each time they press the up or down key.

Comment: mrtsherman, your solution works, now it writes the correct selected value, but...

It replaces everything else on the page. When the user makes a selection, the entire form goes away, and "woman" is the only thing you see at the top left of the page. Can I document.write to another place in the same/original page, while keeping the form on screen? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can modify an existing elements contents to relect the output. This is the preferred way. http://jsfiddle.net/eZg5h/

Answer (score 3):

Declare a `onchange` event handler.

```
document.getElementById('entry_14').onchange = function(){
    var mygender = this.value;
    document.write(mygender);
}
```

Comment: +1 - I actually like this answer better than my own because it doesn't rely on inline javascript declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Add a onChange JS handler to the <select> element. The example below shows an inline way of doing this...

```
<select id="entry_14" onChange="updateMyGender();">
    ....
</select>

<script>
    var mygender = document.getElementById('entry_14').value;
    function updateMyGender()
    {
        mygender = document.getElementById('entry_14').value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
var mygender= document.getElementById('entry_14');
var gender= mygender.options[mygender.selectedIndex].value;// for value 

var gender= mygender.options[mygender.selectedIndex].Text;//for text
```

Comment: `selectedIndex` is only required to support ancient browsers.