# DOM find current selected drop down element

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)
>   [javascript selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/javascript-selected-value)

I have a drop down list for quantities, like this:

```
<select id="Quantity" name="Quantity" class="quantity_select">
    <option id="1" selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I need to use javascript to find the value of the currently selected quantity. When I select e.g. option 2, the selected="selected" doesn't change to the new option. How can I use the DOM to get the current selected quantity?

Thanks

Comment: please share if you have tried some code before posting this Question. There are plenty of questions on SO itself for this logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

HTML

```
<select id="Quantity" name="Quantity" 
        class="quantity_select" onchange="SetValue(this.value)>
    <option id="1" selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
function SetValue(val) {
    alert(val); // This will be the selected value in the drop down
}
```

**Option 2**

If you already have JS in place, and don't want to use option 1, you can simply get the value with `getElementById()`:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('Quantity');
var val = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById('Quantity').value`

Answer (score 2):

USe

```
document.getElementById('Quantity').options[document.getElementById('Quantity').selectedIndex].value;
```