# How can I get a value from an <select> tag using <a href> or link

Tags: javascript, php, button, post, href

Good day! I've got a problem with my code. We all know that we can only get the value of a `<select>` or dropdown through POST and GET method (in submit button) and `document.getElementById` (in `<button>` and pass it through ajax to use it on PHP), my problem is I want to use `<a>` tag because I'm going to generate or download an excel file (using PHPExcel) from the `href` attribute of the `</a>`, the data that will be processed and download by the link will be filtered based on the value of the `<select>`, so is there any possible way to get the value of `<select>`, process it on the page wherein `<a>` will be redirected? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript selected value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/javascript-selected-value)

Comment: Of course it's possible. Share with us what you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean 'from the href' attr? Is there a query string in the href value that you want to pull values from?

Comment: Use javascript to add the parameter to the querystring in the href parameter.

Comment: I mean the link itself, for example, I have a PHP file `form.php` that contains an `<a>` and a `<select>`, in the `<a>` tag, the `href` attribute contains a path "/thispath/Process.php" I want to use the the value that I can get in the `<select>` tag of form.php in Process.php :)