# pass current selected option to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple select list. on select for an option from the list,I am calling a javascript function. I want to pass the current selected option object to this javascript function.

How can I do this? I tried following but its not working.

```
       <select  onClick="callJavascriptFun(this.option);"  >
        </select>
```

Comment: use onchange instead on onclick

Comment: Your answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/javascript-selected-value

Comment: You don't generally need the option, just the value, which would be `this.value`

Comment: I tried its not working

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the option object and not the value

Answer (score 1):

for getting the selected option, try the following code:

```
<select onchange="callJavascriptFun(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);"  >
</select>
```

inside the callJavascriptFun function you will get of course the selected option.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the option object and not the value

Answer (score 0):

Make it easier with event handler:
html part

```
 <select class="list">
 </select>
```

js part:

```
$('select.list').change(function(){
    var selectedOption = $('option:selected', $(this)); // your selected option object(element)
    var current = $(this).val(); // your selected option value
    ....
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the option object and not the value