# Getting the values of a select using onchange function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a value of a select box, using onchange, but when I use `this.val`

```
<select name="type" name="auctionlength" onchange="listing_type();" id="listingtype" class="form-control">
   <option><?php echo System::translate("Choose an option"); ?></option>
   <option value="auction"><?php echo System::translate("Auction"); ?></option>
   <option value="buy"><?php echo System::translate("Buy It Now"); ?></option>
</select>
```

and the following is my function:

```
var listing_type = function()
{
    console.log(this.val);
}
```

I have tried the following instead:

```
this.val();
this.value()
this.value
$(this).val()
$(this).value()
```

But still not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/get-selected-value-text-from-select-on-change

Comment: @TomMillard so you can't use this? you have to select the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

HTML

```
<select name="type" name="auctionlength" onchange="listing_type(this.value);" id="listingtype" class="form-control">
   <option><?php echo System::translate("Choose an option"); ?></option>
   <option value="auction"><?php echo System::translate("Auction"); ?></option>
   <option value="buy"><?php echo System::translate("Buy It Now"); ?></option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function listing_type(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```