# javascript - select option to +100 dollar on element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I would like to make dropdownlist that has two option :
1. special shipping
2. normal shipping

```
<select>
<option>special shipping</option>
<option>normal shipping</option>
</select>
```

I want ,If user choose special shipping, it will +100 dollar on the span element

```
<p><span id="add_dollar"> 5000 </span> dollar </p>
```

and it will be 5100

How could I do?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen OP is clearly using a `<select>`. What relevance does that article have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value/text from Select on change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/get-selected-value-text-from-select-on-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
 var initPrice = 5000;

 $('select').on('change', function() {
   if( this.value == 1 ){
  $('#add_dollar').text(initPrice + 100);
   }else{
  $('#add_dollar').text(initPrice);
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="">Select one</option>
 <option value="1">Special shipping</option>
 <option value="2">Normal shipping</option>
</select>
<p><span id="add_dollar"> 5000 </span> dollar </p>
```

Comment: Can you edit by adding slash to the close span tag? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `change` event on `select` and add its current value to `span`.

```js
var oValue = parseInt($("#add_dollar").text());

$("select").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#add_dollar").text(val == 'special' ? oValue + 100 : oValue)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="special">Special</option>
</select>
<p><span id="add_dollar"> 5000 </span> dollar</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but, I guess it will be problem, if I want to use value of option to insert to database

Comment: @doflamingo why is that a problem?

Comment: because I want to insert "special" string to database so the value should be value="special"

Comment: In that case you can check if value is == `special` like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1444/

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct the syntax mistake in the html (option & span). Here's a plain js solution:

```js
var total = 5000;
var dollar = 100;

var update = function(){
  status = window.event.target.value; //this will check all inputs & selects values
  if(status === 'normal')
    document.getElementById('add_dollar').innerHTML = total;
  if(status === 'special')
    document.getElementById('add_dollar').innerHTML = total + dollar;
};
document.addEventListener("input", update);
```

```html
<select id="shipping">
<option value="normal">normal shipping</option>
<option value="special">special shipping</option>
</select>
<p><span id="add_dollar">5000</span> dollar</p>
```