# How to link to a page when dropdown and checkboxes are marked

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, switch-statement

I have some HTML code that has a few drop down menus and some check boxes and I was wondering how I would go about writing Javascript that would link to a page that specifies their selection. the code is:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <font color="black">
  <div>
    <select name="Days">
  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  <option value="Friday & Saturday">Friday & Saturday</option>
  <option value="Saturday & Sunday">Saturday & Sunday</option>
    <option value="Friday, Saturday, & Sunday">Friday, Saturday, & Sunday</option>

</select>
</form>
  </div>

</div>

<p></p>
<div2>Number of Tickets:</div2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <select name="ticketNumber">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h4>Total:  </h4>
<form action="http://paypal.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h3>Choose Passes</h3>
  <form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male"> VIP<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female"> Meet & Greet<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="other"> Shuttle
</form>
</div>
```

For example: if a user were to select the saturday option, for 2 tickets, with VIP, i'm not sure how i would do either if statements or case statements to link to another page. Hopefully I've been clear enough, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the meaning of 'link to' – whether you're trying to "auto-navigate" the user as soon as they've selected the options, or change where the form submits to once it's submitted, that is.

Either way, the beginning concept is the same: you'll need to [listen to change events on the inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change), [extract the input's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/get-selected-value-text-from-select-on-change/12661801), followed by some kind of logic that maps input values to desired URLs and does with the URL whatever your desired outcome is.

For instance, if each `ticketNumber` maps to some kind of "ticket ID" in, say, a URL query string, you could dynamically change where the form will submit to by changing its `action` property like so:

```
function getUrl(id) {
    return 'https://super-tickets.com/order?id=' + id;
}

var form = document.querySelector('form');

document.querySelector('select[name=ticketNumber]').onchange = function changeEventHandler(event) {
    form.action = getUrl(event.target.value);
}
```