# get selector value after selection?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm curious as to if it is possible to get this selector value after the user selects a value?

```
 <select>
   <option>test1</option>
   <option>test2</option>
 </select>

 //Idea of what i'm trying to accomplish
 select.addEventListener('select',()=>{
     console.log(select.value);
 })
```

I'm trying to use this value data to determine which item to load and view before you submit the form.

Comment: ```select.addEventListener('change'```

Comment: you need to get the element of your selector first. Otherwise select is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value/text from Select on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416767/get-selected-value-text-from-select-on-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to locate your `select` element in the script. To do this, you need to provide it with a specific `id`.

```
<select id="test_selector">
   <option>test1</option>
   <option>test2</option>
 </select>
```

Then you can use this `id` to access that *selector* in the JS. In order to get the updated value, chain it with the `change` event listener. Its callback receives the `event` parameter which contains the info you need.

```
 document.getElementById('test_selector').addEventListener('change', event => {
     console.log(event.target.value);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do it on jquery if you feel more comfy with it

Give your select an id

```
<select id="id_selector">
   <option>test1</option>
   <option>test2</option>
 </select>
```

Use a jquery .change function to get the value of the selected option

```
$('#id_selector').change(function(){
    console.log($('#id_selector').val());
    //or console.log($(this).val()); to make the code shorter
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 select.addEventListener('select',(e)=>{
 console.log(e.target.value);
 })
```

Comment: wrong, and select is undefined

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).