# retrive values of two dropdown boxes without submitting the form

Tags: javascript

I have two dropdown boxes in a single form. How can I alert the values of both the dropdown boxes with onchange function on the second dropdown box without submitting the form.

```
<select name="abc1" id="abc1">
 <option value="a">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select name="abc2" id="abc2" onchange="getvalue()">
 <option value="a">d</option>
 <option value="e">E</option>
 <option value="f">F</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function getValue() {
   alert(document.getElementById('abc1').value);
   alert(document.getElementById('abc2').value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I am a newbie in javascript thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to bypass the form submission by using jquery as shown below:

```
$('#yourFormId').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    alert($('#abc1').val());

    alert($('#abc2').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1- you should try to learn [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) or [Jquery](http://jquery.com) to accomplish these sort of tasks.

2- you should search before asking new questions

these questions have the answers anyway :

[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

[Get drop down value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029281/get-drop-down-value)

Answer (score 0):

Let's write under your html this script

```
<script>
document.getElementById('abc2').onchange = function () {
  alert( 'First value: ' + document.getElementById('abc1').value + '\n' +
         'Second value: ' + this.value ); 
} 
</script>
```